# Handling dtype in a 'for' loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pandas

I'm reading the columns in a pandas dataframe using a *for* loop, using a nested *if* statement to find the minimum and maximum in the datetime range.

I can identify the datetime columns I need, but how can I find the correct way to pass the `column` variable into the `dataframe.series.min()` and `max` statement?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.somedata()

for column in data.columns:

    if data[column].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]':
        data.column.min()
        data.column.max()
```

So when the `column` variable is passed, the loop should return date time values like this:

```
data.DFLT_DT.min()

Timestamp('2007-01-15 00:00:00')


data.DFLT_DT.max()

Timestamp('2016-10-18 00:00:00')
```

Comment: I can take guesses at what you want, but it's best to show us an example.

Comment: You want `if data[col].dtype.name == 'datetime64[ns]':` `dtype` is `np.dtype` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `select_dtypes` to achieve this:

```
In [104]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'int':np.arange(5), 'flt':np.random.randn(5), 'str':list('abcde'), 'dt':pd.date_range(dt.datetime.now(), periods=5)})
df

Out[104]:
                          dt       flt  int str
0 2017-01-18 16:50:13.678037 -0.319022    0   a
1 2017-01-19 16:50:13.678037  0.400441    1   b
2 2017-01-20 16:50:13.678037  0.114614    2   c
3 2017-01-21 16:50:13.678037  1.594350    3   d
4 2017-01-22 16:50:13.678037 -0.962520    4   e

In [106]:
df.select_dtypes([np.datetime64])

Out[106]:
                          dt
0 2017-01-18 16:50:13.678037
1 2017-01-19 16:50:13.678037
2 2017-01-20 16:50:13.678037
3 2017-01-21 16:50:13.678037
4 2017-01-22 16:50:13.678037
```

Then you can get `min,max` on just these cols:

```
In [108]:
for col in df.select_dtypes([np.datetime64]):
    print('column: ', col)
    print('max: ',df[col].max())
    print('min: ',df[col].min())

column:  dt
max:  2017-01-22 16:50:13.678037
min:  2017-01-18 16:50:13.678037
```

To answer why your attempt failed, you're comparing a `np.dtype` object with a string, you want to compare against `np.dtype.name`:

```
In [125]:

for col in df:
    if df[col].dtype.name == 'datetime64[ns]':
        print('col', col)
        print('max', df[col].max())
        print('min', df[col].min())

col dt
max 2017-01-22 16:50:13.678037
min 2017-01-18 16:50:13.678037
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I had to import the `numpy` and `datetime` libraries to get it to work though. `pandas` seems to have some native support for handling `datetime` and `dtype` since when I do `data.col.min()` it returns the value. Just wondering if it can be done natively within `pandas`? (I'm trying to reduce the number of dependencies for the script).

Comment: I don't think you can avoid `numpy` for sure, `datetime` is not necessary here, you can construct a datetime using `pd.to_datetime` also